# Intercepting OpenGLES APIs on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, interceptor, ld-preload

What is the best way of intercepting OpenGLES API on Android platform? Can we use `LD_PRELOAD` to achieve this? Does Android supports `LD_PRELOAD` with out any issues?
Which one of the methods `LD_PRELOAD` and PLT hooking is better to go with?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Android supports LD_PRELOAD with out any issues?

No.

Good ways to do this and do it efficiently are hard. I'd suggest looking at RenderDoc's approach.

*UPDATE* As of Android 10, there are now layer drivers for OpenGL ES, so you can use that mechanism for this.